# Error al intentar "prender" el servidor ssh en mi PC

Tags: git, ssh

Al querer iniciar el servidor de claves ssh en mi computadora con:

```
eval (ssh-agent -s)
```

Me salta el siguiente error:

```
2[main] ssh-agent 388 dofork: child -1 - forked process 5688 died unexpextedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000005, errno 11
fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Esto no me permite agregar mi clave ssh privada al agente para cuando quiera hacer push o pull en git no me pida la contraseña

Comment: No conozco esa forma de manejarlo. Lo que me ha funcionado desde tiempos inmemorables es agregar la llave privada con `ssh-add la-llave-privada`. No te funciona de esa forma?

Comment: Lo intente pero no me deja sin antes activar el servidor creo. me salta lo siguiente: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: Y si en vez de paréntesis usas "backquotes" (``) alrededor de `ssh-agent -s`? Y si todo falla siempre puedes simplemente ejecutar `ssh-agent` sin más, y después copiar y pegar en la terminal los comandos que él mismo te muestre por pantalla.